# Vert.x Test halts with TimeoutException: The test execution timed out

Tags: kotlin, vert.x, junit5

I'm using Vert.x `3.5.3`. I have this (simple) Verticle:

```
class DialPadVerticle : AbstractVerticle() {
  private companion object : KLogging()

  override fun start(future: Future<Void>) {
    vertx.eventBus().consumer(Address.DIALPAD_COMBINATIONS) { message: Message<Int> ->
      val input = message.body()
      logger.info { "Received: $input" }
      message.reply(JsonObject().put("result", DialPad().combinations(input)))
    }
    future.complete()
  }

  override fun stop(future: Future<Void>) {
    logger.debug { "Stopping ${this.javaClass.simpleName} (${deploymentID()})...DONE" }
    future.complete()
  }
}
```

...and I'm trying to build a unit test skeleton for it using the experimental (yet) `vertx-junit5`. So far, I have this:

```
@ExtendWith(VertxExtension::class)
@DisplayName("Dial pad verticle should...")
internal class DialPadVerticleTest {
  @BeforeEach
  fun prepare(vertx: Vertx, testContext: VertxTestContext) {
    vertx.deployVerticle(DialPadVerticle(), testContext.succeeding())
  }

  @Test
  @Throws(Exception::class)
  @DisplayName("Consume Message<Int> correctly")
  fun `consume message correctly`(vertx: Vertx, testContext: VertxTestContext) {
    vertx.eventBus().send<JsonObject>(Address.DIALPAD_COMBINATIONS, 5) {
      // Assertions.assertThat(it.succeeded()).isTrue()
      testContext.verify {
        testContext.completeNow()
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But every time I try to run that from within IntelliJ, I'm getting:

```
java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: The test execution timed out
at io.vertx.junit5.VertxExtension.joinActiveTestContexts(VertxExtension.java:213)
    at io.vertx.junit5.VertxExtension.beforeTestExecution(VertxExtension.java:171)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks$4(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:141)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:40)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeBeforeMethodsOrCallbacksUntilExceptionOccurs(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:155)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:140)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:111)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:58)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$NodeExecutor.lambda$executeRecursively$3(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:113)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SingleTestExecutor.executeSafely(SingleTestExecutor.java:66)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$NodeExecutor.executeRecursively(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:108)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$NodeExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:79)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$NodeExecutor.lambda$executeRecursively$2(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:121)
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:184)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:175)
    at java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:116)
    at java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1801)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471)
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:151)
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:174)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:418)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$NodeExecutor.lambda$executeRecursively$3(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:121)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SingleTestExecutor.executeSafely(SingleTestExecutor.java:66)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$NodeExecutor.executeRecursively(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:108)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$NodeExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:79)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$NodeExecutor.lambda$executeRecursively$2(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:121)
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:184)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:175)
    at java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:116)
    at java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1801)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471)
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:151)
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:174)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:418)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$NodeExecutor.lambda$executeRecursively$3(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:121)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SingleTestExecutor.executeSafely(SingleTestExecutor.java:66)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$NodeExecutor.executeRecursively(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:108)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$NodeExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:79)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:55)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:43)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:170)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:154)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:90)
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:74)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
```

Is this somehow a bug on the `vertx-junit5` library? I've noticed also that, if the Verticles relies on some external config, even though I pass the correct `DeploymentOptions().setConfig(JsonObject().put(...))` as second parameter to `deployVerticle`, it doesn't read those.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran your code and noticed that the execution never reached the test method.

You need to also close your context in `@BeforeEach` methods:

```
@BeforeEach
fun prepare(vertx: Vertx, testContext: VertxTestContext) {
  vertx.deployVerticle(DialPadVerticle(), testContext.succeeding {
    testContext.completeNow()
  })
}
```

`testContext.succeeding` only provides a `AsyncResult` handler that checks that the result succeeded, but it does not mark the whole test context as having completed. It simplifies checking intermediary steps.

Now the test passes just fine!

Comment: There is always. Something. Little. Tiny. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: Perhaps we should add a `completing()` helper method to reduce the boilerplate.

Answer (score 0):

Would you have a minimal reproducer project somewhere?