# Vertx Junit5 Concurrent timeout exception

Tags: unit-testing, asynchronous, vert.x, junit5

I am getting an exception when I am running this code, I am closing the testContext in beforeEach and test Method.

> The test execution timed out. Make sure your asynchronous code includes calls to either VertxTestContext#completeNow(), VertxTestContext#failNow() or Checkpoint#flag()
>   java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: The test execution timed out. Make sure your asynchronous code includes calls to either VertxTestContext#completeNow(), VertxTestContext#failNow() or Checkpoint#flag()
>       at io.vertx.junit5.VertxExtension.joinActiveTestContexts(VertxExtension.java:230)

```
@DisplayName("Test Case Workflow")
@ExtendWith(VertxExtension.class)
public class OrchestrationDBVerticleTest {
    // tag::prepare[]
    private Vertx vertx;
    private OrchestrationDBService service;
    public static final String CONFIG_JDBC_URL = "test.jdbc.url";
    public static final String CONFIG_JDBC_DRIVER_CLASS = "test.jdbc.driver_class";
    public static final String CONFIG_JDBC_MAX_POOL_SIZE = "test.jdbc.max_pool_size";

    @BeforeEach
    public void prepare(VertxTestContext testContext) throws InterruptedException {
        vertx = Vertx.vertx();
        JsonObject config = new JsonObject()
                .put("url", vertx.getOrCreateContext().config().getString(CONFIG_JDBC_URL, "jdbc:hsqldb:mem:testdb"))
                .put("driver_class", vertx.getOrCreateContext().config().getString(CONFIG_JDBC_DRIVER_CLASS, "org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver"))
                .put("max_pool_size", vertx.getOrCreateContext().config().getInteger(CONFIG_JDBC_MAX_POOL_SIZE, 30));
        JsonObject dbConfig = new JsonObject().put("jdbcConfig", config);

        vertx.deployVerticle(new OrchestrationDBVerticle(), new DeploymentOptions().setConfig(dbConfig),
                testContext.succeeding(id -> {
                    service = OrchestrationDBService.createProxy(vertx, OrchestrationDBVerticle.CONFIG_ORCHESTRATION_DB_QUEUE);
                    testContext.completeNow();
                }));
    }
    // end::prepare[]

    // tag::finish[]
    @AfterEach
    public void finish(VertxTestContext testContext) {
        System.out.println("after");
        vertx.close();
    }
    // end::finish[]


    // tag::crud[]
    @Test
    public void crud_operations(VertxTestContext testContext) {
//        Checkpoint callProxy = testContext.checkpoint();
        JsonObject jobInput = (new JsonObject()).put("requestInput", new JsonObject().put("test", "test"))
                .put("workflow", "WorkFlowHandler");
        service.saveJobDetails(jobInput, testContext.succeeding(response -> {
            System.out.println("Service Response : " + response);
            Assertions.assertThat(response.toString().contains("IN_QUEUE"));
            testContext.completeNow();
//            callProxy.flag();
        }));
    }
    // end::crud[]
}
```

EDIT: - 
I was not completing testContext in the finish method.

```
@AfterEach
    public void finish(VertxTestContext testContext) {
        System.out.println("after");
        vertx.close(testContext.succeeding(response -> {
            testContext.completeNow();
        }));
    }
```

But Even after that my asserstion condtions are always true if I provide wrong input.

Comment: I don't believe you should complete the testContext in beforeEach method: this tells the TestContext the test is done without any issue

Comment: @tsegismont, what I found in this link is I should complete.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51490655/vert-x-test-halts-with-timeoutexception-the-test-execution-timed-out

Comment: Oh, right, I missed it

Comment: To fail on assert you should wrap assert by testContext.verify().

Comment: Thanks @Qwertovsky It worked, Can you please help me out in one situation where I want to send one API response to another as a request I am trying but in the second call I am getting null pointer exception.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved.

I was not completing testContext in the finish method.

```
@AfterEach
    public void finish(VertxTestContext testContext) {
        System.out.println("after");
        vertx.close(testContext.succeeding(response -> {
            testContext.completeNow();
        }));
    }
```

Update:- Verifying the assertions in testContext.verify()

```
@Test
    @DisplayName(" Return Exact request what we stored in DB")
    public void crud_operations(VertxTestContext testContext) {
        JsonObject jobInput = (new JsonObject()).put("requestInput", new JsonObject().put("test", "test"))
                .put("workflow", "CaseWorkFlowHandler");
        service.saveJobDetails(jobInput, testContext.succeeding(response -> {
            testContext.verify(() -> {
                Assertions.assertThat(response.getJsonArray("rows").getJsonObject(0).getString("REQUEST_INPUT")).isEqualTo("{\"test\":\"test\"}");
            });
            testContext.completeNow();
        }));
    }
```